# Is it possible to return reactive expressions from a module?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, reactive

I try to return some reactive expressions from one module and pass to another module. I know that such a thing is quite easy when passing inputs e.g.:

```
  return(
    list(
      btn1 = reactive({input$buttonX}),
      btn2 = reactive({input$buttonY}))
   )
```

However, I can't return and pass reactive expressions this way, e.g.:

```
react1 <- reactiveVal()
react2 <- reactiveValues(state = TRUE)

  return(
    list(
      x = react1,
      y = react2
    )
   )
```

When I return reactives this way then in another module the outcome is just... plain text, in this case it's for example *reactiveValues(state = TRUE)*. It's really strange. This method of returning reactives doesn't work in my case.

Is it possible to return already existing reactives in any sensible way?

**EDIT:**

I'm adding reproducible example below. In `mod_1st_Nested_server` I have 3 reactive expr and want to pass one of them to `mod_2nd_Nested_server` through `mod_Parent_server`. This is how it works in my real project and need to do it this way but don't know how:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

moduleServer <- function(id, module) {
   callModule(module, id)
}

# UI 1 #
mod_1st_Nested_UI <- function(id) {
   
   ns <- NS(id)
}

# Server 1 #
mod_1st_Nested_server <- function(id){
   moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
   
     # here I have various reactives but want to pass only some of them to parent      
     btn <- reactive({input$btn})
     info <- reactiveValues(logic = TRUE)
     other <- reactiveVal()
     
     other("XYZ")
     
    return(list(yyy = info))
   })
}


# Parent UI #
mod_Parent_UI <- function(id) {
   
   ns <- NS(id)
   tagList(
      
      mod_1st_Nested_UI(ns('first')),
      mod_2nd_Nested_UI(ns('second'))
   )
}

# Parent Server #
mod_Parent_server <- function(id){
   moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
      
      ns <- NS(id)   
   
      returnReactive <- mod_1st_Nested_server("first")  
      mod_2nd_Nested_server('second', returnReactive$yyy) # here I'm passing reactive from module_1st     
   })
}


# UI 2 #
mod_2nd_Nested_UI <- function(id) {
   
   ns <- NS(id)
   tagList(

      textOutput(ns("text"))     
   )
}


# Server 2 #
mod_2nd_Nested_server <- function(id, value){
   moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
      
      ns <- NS(id)
      
      output$text <- renderText({ # reactive value from 1st module should be printed here
         print(value)
      })      
   })
}


# FINAL App #

ui <- fluidPage(  
   tagList(
      mod_Parent_UI("final")
   ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {   
   mod_Parent_server("final")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: If you're talking about these [Shiny Modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html), I don't see any code relating to these. Can you clarify how modules are being used?

Comment: Sure, I added example to my post. General question is how to pass existing reactives from one module to another. I tried many solutions but in vain.